# Android Game Thread Crashing on Draw()

Tags: android, multithreading, loops

I have implemented a basic game loop in Android for my "Conway's Game of Life" implementation.  It works pretty well but occasionally, it crashes.  To me it looks like Draw() would occasionally be called when the View was no longer valid (sometimes when Home is pressed or sometimes when Options is pressed).

So I did some research and discovered I was probably not implementing onPause()/onResume() correctly.  I have tried to correct this but it is still crashing intermittently.  Not all the time, but enough.

I have been working on this for longer than I care to admit at this point and I was hoping someone that knows more than I, could look at it and tell me if I'm doing anything obviously wrong, maybe a life-cycle problem or something.

Here is my code (note that I have removed some non-related methods for brevity):

```
// Here is the main Android activity
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    Game gameView;

    String mSpeed, mAliveColor, mDeadColor, mBoardSize;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);


        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        mSpeed = prefs.getString("sim_speed", "Fast");
        int iSpeed = 0;

        if(mSpeed.equals("Warp speed"))
            iSpeed = 50;
        if(mSpeed.equals("Fast"))
            iSpeed = 250;
        if(mSpeed.equals("Medium"))
            iSpeed = 500;
        if(mSpeed.equals("Slow"))
            iSpeed = 1000;
        if(mSpeed.equals("Really slow"))
            iSpeed = 2500;

        // Create the Game object
        gameView = new Game(this, iSpeed);

        // register preference change listener
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // and set remembered preferences
        String bs = prefs.getString("sim_board_size", "Large");
        gameView.setBoardSize(bs);

        mAliveColor = prefs.getString("alive_color", "Yellow");           
        gameView.setColor(mAliveColor, "alive");

        mDeadColor = prefs.getString("dead_color", "Blue");    
        gameView.setColor(mDeadColor, "dead");

        setContentView(gameView);
    }

    @Override
protected void onPause() 
{
    //gameView.isSimRunning = false;
    gameView.thread.onPause();

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    //gameView.isSimRunning = true;
    gameView.thread.onResume();
    //gameView.initView();

    super.onResume();
}    
    // handle updates to preferences
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key)
    {
        if(key.equals("sim_speed"))
        {
            mSpeed = prefs.getString("sim_speed", "Fast");

            if(mSpeed.equals("Warp speed"))
                gameView.setSpeed(50);
            if(mSpeed.equals("Fast"))
                gameView.setSpeed(250);
            if(mSpeed.equals("Medium"))
                gameView.setSpeed(500);
            if(mSpeed.equals("Slow"))
                gameView.setSpeed(1000);
            if(mSpeed.equals("Really slow"))
                gameView.setSpeed(5000);
        }

        if(key.equals("sim_board_size"))
        {
            mBoardSize = prefs.getString("sim_board_size", "Large");

            gameView.setBoardSize(mBoardSize);
        }

        if(key.equals("alive_color"))
        {
            mAliveColor = prefs.getString("alive_color", "Yellow");

            gameView.setColor(mAliveColor, "alive");
        }

        if(key.equals("dead_color"))
        {
            mDeadColor = prefs.getString("dead_color", "Blue");

            gameView.setColor(mDeadColor, "dead");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Create a menu inflater
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        // Generate a Menu from the XML menu resource file
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
}

// Here is the SurfaceView class
public class Game extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    long lastUpdate = 0;
    long sleepTime=0;

    public int                 num_cols = 51;
    public int                 max_cols = 51;
    public int                 num_rows = 81;
    public int                 max_rows = 81;

    public long                gmDelay = 0;
    private int                grid_cell_size = 9;

    public boolean [][]        current_life   = new boolean [max_cols][max_rows];
    private boolean [][]       successor_gen  = new boolean [max_cols][max_rows];

    public boolean             isSimRunning = false;
    public boolean             isThreadStarted = false;

    Paint dead_paint = new Paint();
    Paint alive_paint = new Paint();
    Paint background = new Paint();

    private GameThread thread;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Context context;

    public Game(Context context, int dly) 
    {
        super(context);

        dead_paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        dead_paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        alive_paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        alive_paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        background.setStrokeWidth(0);
        background.setColor(Color.BLACK);        

        gmDelay = dly;

        initView();
        initLifeArray();
    }

    public void setSpeed(long s)
    {
        gmDelay = s;

        initView();

        thread.delay = s;
    }

    public void setBoardSize(String s)
    {
        thread.state = 2;
        isSimRunning = false;

        if(s.equals("Small"))
            num_cols = 10;
        else if(s.equals("Medium"))
            num_cols = 25;
        else if(s.equals("Large"))
            num_cols = 51;

        thread.state = 1;
        isSimRunning = true;

        initView();
    }

    public void setColor(String color, String type)
    {
        int c = 0;

        // violet, white and orange

        if(color.equals("Black"))
            c = Color.BLACK;
        else if(color.equals("Blue"))
            c = Color.BLUE;
        else if(color.equals("Green"))
            c = Color.GREEN;
        else if(color.equals("Purple"))
            c = Color.rgb(109, 6, 108);
        else if(color.equals("Orange"))
            c = Color.rgb(255, 157, 30);
        else if(color.equals("Red"))
            c = Color.RED;
        else if(color.equals("Yellow"))
            c = Color.YELLOW;
        else if(color.equals("White"))
            c = Color.WHITE;
        else
            c = Color.YELLOW;

        if(type.equals("alive"))
            alive_paint.setColor(c);
        else
            dead_paint.setColor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event != null)
        {
            int x = (int) event.getX()/grid_cell_size;
            int y = (int) event.getY()/grid_cell_size;

            int max_x = current_life.length;

            if(x < max_x)
            {
                int max_y = current_life[x].length;

                if(y < max_y)
                    current_life[x][y] = true;
            }

            return true;      
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    void initView()
    {
        // Initialize our screen holder
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        // Initialize our Thread class. A call will be made to start it later
        thread = new GameThread(holder, context, new Handler(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void Draw(Canvas canvas) 
    {


            int x = canvas.getWidth();
            int y = canvas.getHeight();

            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x, y, background);

            grid_cell_size = (int) Math.ceil((double) (x / num_cols) * 1.0);
            int gap = grid_cell_size - 1;

            for(int col = 0; col < num_cols; col++)  
            {
                for(int row = 0; row < num_rows; row++) 
                {
                    if(current_life[col][row])
                        canvas.drawRect(col*grid_cell_size, row*grid_cell_size, col*grid_cell_size+gap, row*grid_cell_size+gap, 

alive_paint);
                    else
                        canvas.drawRect(col*grid_cell_size, row*grid_cell_size, col*grid_cell_size+gap, row*grid_cell_size+gap, 

dead_paint);
                }
            }

    }

    // These methods are overridden from the SurfaceView super class. They are automatically called 
    // when a SurfaceView is created, resumed or suspended.
    @Override 
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int format, int width, int height)
    {

    }

    @Override 
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override 
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) 
    {
    if (!isThreadStarted) {
        thread.start();
        isThreadStarted = true;
    } 

    thread.onResume();

    }


}

// Finally, we have the thread class
public class GameThread extends Thread 
{
    // flag to hold game state
    // private static final String TAG = GameThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private Game game;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    //for consistent rendering
    private long sleepTime;
    public long delay=250;

    //state of game (Running or Paused).
    int state = 1;
    public final static int RUNNING = 1;
    public final static int PAUSED = 2;
    private Object mPauseLock = new Object();  
    private boolean mPaused = false;

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context, Handler handler, Game g)
    {
        super();

        //data about the screen
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;

        delay = g.gmDelay;

        this.game = g;
    }

public void onPause() 
{
    state = 2;

    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = true;
    }
}

public void onResume()
{
    state = 1;

    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = false;
        mPauseLock.notifyAll();
    }
}

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        while (state == RUNNING  && ! mPaused) 
        {
            delay = this.game.gmDelay;

            //time before update
            long beforeTime = System.nanoTime();

            // Update the simulation one generation
            game.createNextGeneration();

            Canvas c = null;

            try 
            {
                //lock canvas so nothing else can use it
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) 
                {
                    //if(game.isSimRunning)
                        game.Draw(c);
                }
            } 
            finally 
            {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an inconsistent state
                if (c != null) 
                {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }

            synchronized (mPauseLock) {
                while (mPaused) {
                    try {
                        mPauseLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            // Sleep time. Time required to sleep to keep game consistent
            // This starts with the specified delay time (in milliseconds) then subtracts from that the actual
            // time it took to update and render the game. This allows the simulation to render smoothly.
            this.sleepTime = delay-((System.nanoTime()-beforeTime)/1000000L);

            try 
            {
                //actual sleep code
                if(sleepTime>0)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(GameThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple change would be to call thread.start() from our onResume(), and change state so it's not runnnig in onPause(). Then the thread starts every time onResume() is called (which I believe is what you want, since the surface should only ever be created once per game).

Comment: I am not actually getting an error.  Currently when I run the app, I simply get a black screen.  Previously, I could see the grid I am trying to draw.  In the debugger I do not see my Thread's run() method being invoked.

Comment: You would call thread.start() from onResume?  I'm assuming you mean from onResume() in my MainActivity?  Something like gameView.thread.start() after I create the gameView object?  And then remove the code from surfaceCreated()?

Comment: UPDATE:  I have updated the question and the code.  The thread is now running.  But it crashes intermittently.  I am getting an exception in Draw intermittently when Home is pressed.  Like it's trying to Draw after the surfaceView is destroyed.  But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks for any suggestions!!

Comment: When you say crashes, can you tell us about the exception and stacktrace?  Null Pointer?  Or is it a problem in native code?

Comment: I am getting a 'FATAL EXCEPTION'.  java.lang.NullPointerException at Game.Draw() at GameThread.run()

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by checking to see if canvas is null in Draw() before performing any operations.

Thanks for all the suggestions and comments!!